# Passing Argument as object to invoke

Tags: java, reflection

```
    String className = "com.endpoints.EndPointImpl"; 
    String methodName = "add";
    String args = "2,3";


    try {

        Class<?> clas = Class.forName(className);
        Object obj = Class.forName(className).newInstance(); 
        java.lang.reflect.Method method = null;
        //Type[] types;

        for(java.lang.reflect.Method m :obj.getClass().getMethods())
        {
            if(m.getName().equals(methodName))
            {
                method = m;
                //types = m.getParameterTypes();
                break;
            }
        }

//java.lang.reflect.Method method = clas.getDeclaredMethod(methodName,t);


        Object[] strarr =  args.split(",");

        Object retobj = method.invoke(obj,strarr );
```

how to i pass arguments to invoke as of now it is generating exception i know why but how can i pass two int

add(in,int)

P.S.

```
ArrayList<Object> objArr = new ArrayList<Object>();

        for(java.lang.reflect.Method m :obj.getClass().getMethods())
        {
            if(m.getName().equals(methodName))
            {
                method = m;

                int index = 0;
                for(Type type :m.getGenericParameterTypes())
                {
                    if(type.getClass().equals("Integer"))
                    {
                        objArr.add(Integer.parseInt(strarr[index]));
                    }
                    else if(type.getClass().equals("Float"))
                    {
                        objArr.add(Float.parseFloat(strarr[index]));
                    }
                    index++;
                }
```

and then pass the objArr in invoke or there is a better solution, i want to also ask if it is possible to create a generic convert function so that it will conver the string to specified type

Comment: Can you please confirm if method signature is Object add(Object,Object) or Object add(int,int)

Answer (score 1):

When writing code, you should always ask yourself what you should be doing. The best way to answer this is to read the Javadoc. Also, please always provide full stacktraces when you get exceptions. You don't need your whole `for` loop.

Use [`Method#getDeclaredMethod(String, Class[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29). It accepts two arguments

```
name - the name of the method
parameterTypes - the parameter array
```

If the method is named `add` and accepts two `int` arguments, call it like this

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method = clas.getDeclaredMethod("add", int.class, int.class);
```

The `int.class` arguments are the type of parameters the method takes.

You can [invoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) the method with

```
method.invoke(object, 3, 3);
```

where object is an instance of the class declaring `add(int, int)` method. If this method is `static`, you could pass `null` instead. The two `3`s are the `int` argument values you would pass as if you were calling the method directly.

```
object.add(3,3);
```

If you are receiving Strings to pass in as arguments, you need to cast them first

```
String args = "2,3";
String[] strarr =  args.split(",");
// with no other validation
int[] values = new int[strarr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < strarr.length; i++) {
    values[i] = Integer.parseInt(strarr[i]);
}

method.invoke(object, values);
```

Obviously, perform the appropriate validation when splitting and parsing the Strings.

Comment: actually arguments are coming in string e.g(args="2,1") and i know i am passing it as string that is causing the exception

Comment: Then you need to parse those to an `int` array and pass that.

Comment: found this public static <T> T parseObjectFromString(String s, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
    return clazz.getConstructor(new Class[] {String.class }).newInstance(s);
}

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace this statement String args = "2,3"; with Integer args = {10,20};
2. Remove this statement Object[] strarr =  args.split(",");
3. Replace  Object retobj = method.invoke(obj,strarr ); with  Object retobj = method.invoke(obj,args);